# Copy text from label in xamarin.forms

Tags: text, xamarin.forms, copy, label, xamarin.forms.entry

I'm quite new to `Xamarin.Forms`. I have started to create an application which will display large amount of text retrieved from a book. At the moment I add the text into a `Label`, however the user can't copy the text he sees on the screen in any of the three platforms.

Is there a way to enable copying of text from a label in `Xamarin.Forms`? I have tried with `Editor` as well, it works to copy the data when pushed into `Editor`, however user can enter characters which is what I don't want them to do. I just want to show the text that I have read in from the stream and make it possible for the user to copy the amount of text he wishes. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you can use a button, or add a gesture to the label, that will copy the label text to the clipboard.

Comment: You can subclass the editor and override the text changed event to prevent users from altering the text.

Comment: try to create a renderer and make it read only

Comment: cannot override TextChanged because its not marked as virtual, abstract or override, thanks anyways @slepz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advise would be to use webview instead if you want to display text that a user should be able to copy using the native copy mechanisms.
The text will have to be in html code that is added to the webview.
Look at the following guide for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 2):

Can you try below

Page.Xaml

```
<Entry TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged" Text="EnteyText" Unfocused="Handle_Unfocused" Focused="Handle_Focused" x:Name="entry" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>
<Button Text="Bind Text From Book" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" />
```

Page.Xaml.CS

```
    bool isFocused;
    string entryText="EnteyText";

    void Handle_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        isFocused = e.IsFocused;
    }

        void Handle_Unfocused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            isFocused = e.IsFocused;
        }

        void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isFocused)
            {
                entryText = (sender as Entry).Text;
            }
            if (isFocused && entryText != e.NewTextValue)
            {
                (sender as Entry).Text = e.OldTextValue;
            }
        }

        void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            entry.Unfocus();
            entry.Text = "Text from book";
        }
```